# Getting Bad Request Error while using sendgrid through python

Tags: python, sendgrid

I am getting a bad request error from sendgrid while trying to send out an email with attachments

```py
import base64
import os
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (
    Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName,
    FileType, Disposition, ContentId)
import urllib.request as urllib
import os
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='xxx@gmail.com',
    to_emails='xxx@gmail.com',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\xxx.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment.file_name = FileName('test_filename.pdf')
attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment.content_id = ContentId('PDF Document file')
message.attachment = attachment
try:
    sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\sendgrid\sendgrid.py", line 98, in send
    response = self.client.mail.send.post(request_body=message.get())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 262, in http_request
    self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 178, in _make_request
    raise exc
python_http_client.exceptions.BadRequestsError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the encoding of my pdf. How do I make sure it is base64 encoded?

Comment: Could you please include the error message and stack?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't just comment even though this isn't an actual "solution," per se. SendGrid is likely sending a more helpful message along with the BadRequest, which you can view by using `HTTPError` like this:

```
from python_http_client.exceptions import HTTPError

sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
try:
    response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.to_dict)
```

from: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#error

Hopefully, this will help you actually fix the issue! The full list of error codes can be found here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code shown. I came across this question today trying to solve my own issue (definitely unrelated to what you're experiencing), but `base64.b64encode(data).decode()` is exactly the same as what I have in my working example with a pdf.

Comment: This is not the correct answer to fix the issue but it surely help to debug the issue

Comment: Worked well with "except python_http_client.exceptions.BadRequestsError as e:", thanks!